# php for loop with decimal point

Tags: php, loops

I have this code below

```
public function score(){
    $score = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i += 0.5){
      $score[] = $i;
    }
    return $score;
  }
```

this will return `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5`

how can i achieved like this ->  `0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0`?

Comment: That link should give you the right answer. Note that you'll be turning it into a string.

Comment: okay @Pikamander2..thank you

Comment: it's okay now..thanks again @Pikamander2